# Filter in knockout displaying empty Select List

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am doing some filtering with Knockout. I have written this code Please have a look.

```
        $(function() {
        var viewmodel = (function () {
            var filter = ko.observable("");
            var productsList = ko.observableArray([
                {
                    ProductName: "Sunsilk",
                    ProductCategory:"Shampo"
                },
                {
                    ProductName: "Badminton",
                    ProductCategory: "Sports"
                },
                {
                    ProductName: "Chicken",
                    ProductCategory: "Meat"
                },
                {
                    ProductName: "Head and Shoulder",
                    ProductCategory: "Shampo"
                },
                {
                    ProductName: "Book",
                    ProductCategory: "Education"
                },
                {
                    ProductName: "Pen",
                    ProductCategory: "Education"
                }

            ]);

            return {
                productsList: productsList,
                filter: filter,



            };
        }());
        viewmodel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
            var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
            if (!filter) {
                return this.productsList();
            } else {
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.productsList, function (item) {
                    return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(this.item.ProductCategory.toLowerCase(), filter);
                });
            }
        }, viewmodel);
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);

    });
```

and below is the HTML

```
<h4> << Decision based on filter >> </h4>
        <p><span>Filter: </span><input data-bind="value:filter" type="text" name="filterbox"/>    <button name="filter">Filter</button></p>
        <select data-bind="options:filteredItems,optionsText:'ProductName'" multiple="multiple" size="3"></select>
```

The filter doesn't work . I am stuck can anyone help me out please. If the given filter value is null or empty all of the products are returned which is okay. But when I write the specific category for the products none of the products are returned.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b77AT/4/)

Comment: first change this.item.ProductCategory.toLowerCase to item.ProductCategory.toLowerCase

Comment: I have changed and now the console is giving me the following error. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b77AT/3/).

Comment: ok @raheelshan let me make a fiddle there !

Comment: @raheelshan link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b77AT/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is small mistake in code that under computed "**if**" condition always returning true whenever you enter any value and i have also changed the filtering logic.

```
 viewmodel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
   var filter = viewmodel.filter().toLowerCase();
   if (!filter && filter === "") {
     return viewmodel.productsList();
   } else {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewmodel.productsList(), function (item) {
        if (item.ProductCategory) {
            return item.ProductCategory.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;//will return true if ProductCategory contains the filter string
        }
    });
  }

 }, viewmodel);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nV5gN/)

Comment: by the way I am wondering why ko.utils.stringStartsWith() didn't worked ? any thoughts on that!

Comment: Actually ko.utils.stringStartsWith is not exported in the minified KO file so if you are working with minified ko it won't work. see this fiddle with ko.utils.stringStartsWith http://jsfiddle.net/Akhlesh/nV5gN/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
viewmodel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
        var filter = viewmodel.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return viewmodel.productsList();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewmodel.productsList, function (i,item) {
   if(item.ProductCategory)
   {
                return   ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.ProductCategory.toString().toLowerCase(), filter);
   }
            });
        }
    }, viewmodel);
```